# How to make a Regex that specifies elements in any order?

Tags: regex

I want a regex that matches a string which contains

```
 - At least one brace: } or {  
and
 - At least one digit: \d  
and
 - At least one instance of either: <p> or </p>
```

But in any order, so that all the following would be matched:

```
<p>{123

2}</p>

2<p>}}}

{}{}{}<p></p></p>234234}}}
```

And none of these would be matched:

```
<p>{ alphabet 123

{2}

{{{}}}

<p>1</p>
```

Here's what I have so far, which demands only one of any of those components:

```
(<\/p>|<p>|\d|\}|\{)+
```

My problem is that I don't know how to make it more general without also having to specify the order like this:

```
(<\/p>|<p>)+(\d)+(\}|\{)+
```

Or making it stupidly long to enumerate every possible order...

How can I say "Needs at least one of each of these components in any order?"

Thanks.

Comment: Why <p>{ alphabet 123 is not a match?

Comment: Why this <p>{ alphabet 123 string is not valid?

Comment: @Stook and @Shekhar: because he never said an alphabet is possible; he only said brace, digit, `<p>`, or `</p>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your regex flavor supports lookaheads, you can use positive lookahead as:

```
^(?=.*(\{|\}))(?=.*\d)(?=.*(<p>|<\/p>)).*$
```

This regex uses positive lookahead to assert that the string as atleast one of either `{` or `}`, at least one digit and atleast one of either `<p>` or `</p>`.

If you want to ensure that the string has only these and nothing else can use the regex:

```
^(?=.*(\{|\}))(?=.*\d)(?=.*(<p>|<\/p>))(<\/p>|<p>|\d|\}|\{)*$
```

which works as previous regex but also ensures that the input has no other character.

[**Regex implemented in Perl**](http://www.ideone.com/oOLH6)

The regex can be made a bit shorter as:

```
^(?=.*[{}])(?=.*\d)(?=.*<\/?p>)(<\/?p>|[\d}{])*$
```

which makes use of the fact that `\{|\}` is same as `[{}]`, `<p>|<\/p>` is same as `<\/?p>`.

Comment: <\/?p> matches both <p> and </p> and nothing else. It doesn't exactly make the regex simpler, but it definitely makes it a lot shorter, and possibly a bit cleaner.

Comment: @EmFi: You are right. I've edited my post to include your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I'm working in Ruby so I'll have to fiddle a little to get it working, but you've set me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you'll just have to check three expressions

Comment: Well, 9 right? In this simplified example anyway. The principal is to avoid cases where you might want to match more complex things and it blows into the thousands very quickly.

Comment: Only three if you're talking full expressions... if (x ~= /a/ and x ~= /b/ and x ~= /c/).  You only get the combinatorial blowout you mention when you really must test them all in one regexp comparison and don't have the Perl-style lookaheads mentioned by codaddict.